# vee-validate in steps form

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

I have a problem I'm trying to learn vee-validate 
to a form that has steps but the problem is like as far 
as the first drop I validate correctly a field from the second step is no longer works properly or someone could help this is all component and methods i think this is scope problem but i don't now?

````
<template>
  <div>
      <div v-if="step === 1">
        <input
          class="form-control loginForm__input"
          type="text"
          :class="{'input': true, 'is-invalid': errors.has('email') }"
          name="email"
          v-validate="'required|email'"
          placeholder="Email adress"
          v-model="registration.email"
        />
      </div>
      <div v-if="step === 2">
        <input
          class="form-control loginForm__input"
          :class="{'input': true, 'is-invalid': errors.has('nameFirst') }"
          v-validate="'required'"
          name="nameFirst"
          type="text"
          placeholder="name"
          v-model="registration.nameFirst"
        />
      <div class="LoginButton">
        <button
          type="button"
          class="btn button__blue"
          @click="nextStep();progressbarNext();"
        >Continue</button>
      </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "Register",
  components: {
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      step: 1,
      registration: {
        email: null,
        nameFirst: null,
      }
    };
  },
  computed: {},
  methods: {
    goBack() {
      if (this.step === 1) {
        this.$router.push("/");
        return;
      }
      this.step--;
    },
    nextStep() {
      this.$validator.validateAll().then(result => {
        console.log(result);
        if (result) {
          if (this.step === 3) {
            this.showModal = true;
            (this.stepBannerThree = true), (this.step = 3);
            return;
          }
          this.step++;
          if (this.step == 2) {
            return (this.stepBannerOne = true);
          }
          if (this.step == 3) {
            return (this.stepBannerTwo = true);
          }
          return;
        }
      });
    },
  }
};
</script> ```
````